# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 - node deploy.js

Tags: json

My code keeps returning SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0.
It deploys from accounts[0] but it does not return a "deployed to" address.
I've tried stringify as well.

I'm new to JS and I'm taking first steps in building my own project.
I had the same problem at my compile.js file but solved it with JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input). It doesn't seem to work here.

Can someone help?

Here's my deploy.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { interface, bytecode } = require("./compile");

const compiledPurchase = require("./build/Purchase.json");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
"12 words",
"testnet"
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async() => {
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

console.log("Attempting to deploy from account", accounts[0]);
// #####Deploy script#####

const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(
        JSON.parse(compiledPurchase.interface)
    )
    .deploy({ data: compiledPurchase.bytecode })
    .send({ gas: "1000000", from: accounts[0] });
console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Comment: Are you using truffle to compile contracts?

Comment: I am, yes. Had an issue with JSON.parse on the compile.js too but solved it with stringify. Haven’t been able to solve this one though.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the path you are giving is correct and complete in this line:

```
const compiledPurchase = require("./build/Purchase.json");
```

Path to the folder could be different. That depends on your Project directory structure. But when you compile with truffle, it generates a json file in `build/contracts` folder.

Then change your deployment script like this:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(compiledPurchase.abi)

contract.deploy({ data: compiledPurchase.bytecode })
    .send({ gas: "1000000", from: accounts[0] })
    .then(function(result){
       console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address)
    });
```